# Problem in communicating props in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am not getting the choosen program option to select user,The props supposed to communicate from program.js to enrollmentform can anyone help me figuring out why the choosen program is not appearing

```
 the code is --:


My App.js Code is ---:

import './App.css';
import EnrollmentForm from './EnrollmentForm';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <EnrollmentForm >Just React</EnrollmentForm>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

My enrollmentform.js code is ---:

import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
function EnrolmentForm(props) {
 const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
 const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
 const [welcomeMessage, setWelcomeMessage] = useState("");
 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
 setWelcomeMessage(`Welcome ${firstName} ${lastName}`);
 event.preventDefault();
 };
 return (
 <div>
 <form className="enrolForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
 <h1>{props.chosenProgram} Student Details</h1>
 <label>First name:</label>
 <input
 type="text"
 name="fname"
 onBlur={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
 />
 <br />
 <label>Last name:</label>
 <input
 type="text"
 name="lname"
 onBlur={(event) => setLastName(event.target.value)}
 />
 <br />
 <br />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 <br />
 <label id="studentMsg" className="message">
 {welcomeMessage}
 </label>
 </form>
 </div>
 );
}
export default EnrolmentForm;
my program.js code is ---:



import "./App.css";
import EnrolmentForm from "./EnrolmentForm";
import { useState } from "react";
function App() {
 const [program, setProgram] = useState("UG");
 const handleChange = (event) => {
 setProgram(event.target.textContent);
 };
 return (
 <div className="App">
 <div className="programs">
 <label>Choose Program:</label>
 <select className="appDropDowns"
 onChange={handleChange}
 value={program} >

 <option value="UG">Undergraduate</option>
 <option value="PG">Postgraduate</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 <EnrolmentForm chosenProgram={program} />
 </div>
 );
}
```

The desired output supposed to be--->

[image: The desired output supposed to be]

and the output which I am getting
[image: and the output which I am getting]

There supposed to be a option of choosen program but it is not working and not apearing when I run the code

Comment: Because you are rendering Enrollment Form Component instead of rendering Program Component. In App Component use program component. And Also name of your program.js component is App rename it to Program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code Should Look like This:
In App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import Program from './Program';
        
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Program />
    </div>
  );
}
    
export default App;
```

In Enrollment.js code:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";

function EnrolmentForm(props) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [welcomeMessage, setWelcomeMessage] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    setWelcomeMessage(`Welcome ${firstName} ${lastName}`);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="enrolForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1>{props.chosenProgram} Student Details</h1>
        <label>First name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="fname"
          onBlur={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <label>Last name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lname"
          onBlur={(event) => setLastName(event.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <br />
        <label id="studentMsg" className="message">
          {welcomeMessage}
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EnrolmentForm;
```

And Program.js code:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";
import EnrolmentForm from "./EnrolmentForm";

function Program() {
  const [program, setProgram] = useState("UG");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setProgram(event.target.textContent);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="programs">
        <label>Choose Program:</label>
        <select
          className="appDropDowns"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={program}
        >
          <option value="UG">Undergraduate</option>
          <option value="PG">Postgraduate</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <EnrolmentForm chosenProgram={program} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Program;
```